# Problem with align alignment

Tags: equations, align

I have written the following code:

```
\mathbb{R}^n\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^n&\rightarrow 
\mathbb{R}^m\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
(v_1,\cdots,v_k)&\mapsto (f_*(v_1),\cdots,f_*(v_k))\mapsto
 \eta(f_*(v_1),\cdots,f_*(v_k))
```

I am using `&` symbol two times..

I want output for `(v_1,\cdots,v_k)` to come under

```
\mathbb{R}^n\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^n
```

and `(f_*(v_1),\cdots,f_*(v_k))` to come under

```
\mathbb{R}^m\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^m
```

and `\eta(f_*(v_1),\cdots,f_*(v_k))` to come under

```
\mathbb{R}
```

First two steps are coming perfectly, but

```
\eta(f_*(v_1),\cdots,f_*(v_k))
```

is not coming under

```
\mathbb{R}
```

There is some gap. What am i supposed to do to clear this gap?

The following is what i have in my tex file

```
\documentclass[article]{amsart}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\textheight 9.3in \textwidth 6.5in \topmargin -1cm
\oddsidemargin-.05cm \evensidemargin -.1cm \topmargin .1cm
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage{xypic}
\author{..}
\title{..}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{R}^n\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^n &\rightarrow     \mathbb{R}^m\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^m &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
(v_1,\cdots,v_k) &\mapsto (f_*(v_1),\cdots,f_*(v_k)) &\mapsto \eta(f_*   (v_1),\cdots,f_*(v_k))
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need 2n-1 `&`'s, one for each alignment sets, and one between each alignment. BTW: On this site we prefer users to post full minimal examples including document class and preamble. It makes it a lot easier to help. BTW2: replace `,\cdots,` with `,\dots,`

Comment: @daleif I have edited it.. Please see if you can help me with this

Comment: First of, it might be a good idea to look at your own code. It does not even compile.

Comment: Now it works... :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a different construction, and I'd not even align them because of the vast size difference.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\mathbb{R}^n\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^n 
& \rightarrow
\mathbb{R}^m\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^m
&& \to \mathbb{R}
\\
 (v_1,\dots,v_k)&\mapsto (f_*(v_1),\dots,f_*(v_k))
 &&\mapsto \eta(f_ (v_1),\dots,f_*(v_k))
\end{alignat*}

Better
\begin{gather*}
\mathbb{R}^n\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^n 
 \rightarrow
\mathbb{R}^m\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^m
 \to \mathbb{R}
\\
 (v_1,\dots,v_k)\mapsto (f_*(v_1),\dots,f_*(v_k))
\mapsto \eta(f_ (v_1),\dots,f_*(v_k))
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, so it is not possible to get that third arrow right above third arrow that is below due to size difference..

Comment: I can not upvote as i do not have 15 reputation... Once i get that i will do upvote your answer

Comment: @kklm in the first part of the image the two arrows are above each other, but it looks strange

Comment: Updated with a fix of the wrongly used `\cdots`

Answer (score 1):

For the utmost in flexibility and programmability, you may want to set up an `array` environment to display the two rows. The following code right-aligns the material in the first group, centers the material in the middle group, and left-aligns the material in the final group; the `\rightarrow` and `\mapsto` symbols are center-set in columns of type `C`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{ rCcCl }
  \R^n\times\dots\times\R^n & \rightarrow &
     \R^m\times\dots\times\R^m & \rightarrow & \R \\
  (v_1,\dots,v_k) & \mapsto & 
     \bigl(f_*(v_1),\dots,f_*(v_k)\bigr) & \mapsto & 
     \eta\bigl(f_*(v_1),\dots,f_*(v_k)\bigr) \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

If you'd like to center-set the material in all three groups instead, simply replace `\begin{array}{ rCcCl }` with `\begin{array}{ cCcCc }`.